# Does higher activation value mean a neuron is important in neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, activation-function

Suppose I have a deep neural network for classification purposes, which consists of two hidden layers, 50 neurons in each layer and "**Relu**" as the activation function. The output of the activation function ranges from 0 to +1 in my model. Now, is there any way to say a higher activation value (say close to 1) of a neuron means the neuron is more important compared to a neuron which has lower activation value (close to 0)?

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by “important.”

Comment: @JohnWu I want to find out if there are neurons that are activated for a particular class. I was thinking of using the activation values as a measurement. So does higher activation value mean something?